Question about regularity of a nonlinear PDE
Suppose $\Omega$ is a bounded domain with Lipschitz boundary. I know that u is a solution to a nonlinear pde which takes the form $Lu+u^2=0$ and $u\in H^{1}_{0}$, where $L$ is a linear elliptic operator. Now I can write $Lu=-u^2$ so that I can view $u$ as a solution to $Lu=g$ with $g=-u^2$.
My question is if I also know that $u^2\in L^2$, can I conclude that $u\in H^2$ and $||u||_{H^2}\leq C||g||_{L^{2}}$ by using regularity theory of linear elliptic equation?

Yes. Please check the standard literature on how to use certain boostrapping argument to show regularity estimates for semi-linear elliptic PDEs.

@ShuhaoCao Thank you very much! I'll look it up.
